# Using CMFCMenuButton::SizeToContent does not seem to work as I would like. Why?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am perplexed about the `SizeToContent` method of the `CMFCMenuButton` control.

This is my dialog in the IDE:

[image]

As you can see, I have specifically made the button wider than the two on the far right.

I added the following code to `OnInitDialog`:

```
// Resize (if required)
const auto sizNewButton = m_btnReset.SizeToContent(true);
CRect rctButton;
m_btnReset.GetWindowRect(&rctButton);
if(sizNewButton.cx > rctButton.Width())
{
    m_btnReset.SizeToContent();
}
```

Yet, when I run my application in English:

[image]

It has made it smaller. My application supports 50+ languages by using satellite DLLs and I was hoping to only resize to content if it was required. But it seems to resize it anyway. Have I missed a step here?

I have checked the properties for the control in the IDE and it is not set to auto resize:

[image]

I notice that the help documentation states:

> The new size of the button is calculated to fit the button text, image, and arrow. The framework also adds in **predefined margins of 10 pixels for the horizontal** edge and 5 pixels for the vertical edge.

I had a look at my button:

- Default size: 48 x 23 (the `GeWindowRect` result).
- Calculated size: 57 x 23 (the `SizeToContent` result).

If I adjusted my code like this:

```
if((sizNewButton.cx - 10) > rctButton.Width())
```

That would bring it down to 47 and thus would not resize. I am assuming the code is not working right because of the padded margin that `GetWindowRect` knows nothing about.

Comment: It's not actually the `SizeToContent()` function that doesn't work properly, it's the MFC subclassing that perplexes it. Both `SizeToContent()` and `GetWindowRect()` work right, the problem is that `GetWindowRect()` is called after the control was subclassed, and (due to MFC's rather poor implementation) the original size was lost. You can test this easily, just duplicate the `IDC_MENUBUTTON_RESET` control but do not subclass it (assign it to a control variable), it works then. Only a "workaround" would be feasible here, not a true "fix".

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I am not sure what you mean by me subclassing it. All I have done is map it to a control variable via `DoDataExchange` and attach the required menu resource. No subclassing on my part.

Comment: Controls like `CMFCMenuButton`, `CMFCButton` etc are not standard Win32 controls, they are MFC custom controls (subclasses), and I mentioned MFC's subclassing, not yours. By mapping it to a control variable you are also using the subclassed control. Pls do the test with the duplicate (but not mapped) control while I'm looking for a workaround...

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou So you want me to map it to a normal `CButton`? Sorry if I am not getting you.

Comment: No, just don't map it to any control variable (for the test only).

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I confirm that the width is indeed different. But, it seems at the moment I have to use SizeToContent anyway because if I don't it automatically shows smaller sized that default design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searched it, and found that the problem is MFC's `CMFCMenuButton::SizeToContent()` implementation in afxmenubutton.cpp:

```
CSize CMFCMenuButton::SizeToContent(BOOL bCalcOnly)
{
    CSize size = CMFCButton::SizeToContent(FALSE); // <==== The culprit!!!
    size.cx += CMenuImages::Size().cx;

    if (!bCalcOnly)
    {
        SetWindowPos(NULL, -1, -1, size.cx, size.cy, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    }

    return size;
}
```

That is, it calls the base implementation of `SizeToContent()` with the `bCalcOnly` parameter set to `FALSE`, which means it will also resize the control to just fit the text (without the drop-down arrow). This is less than required for the text plus the arrow, and of course the original size is lost.

A workaround can be get the (original) width, before the `SizeToContent()` call, and work with this instead of the new one:

```
CRect rctButton;
m_btnReset.GetWindowRect(&rctButton);
const auto nOrigWidth = rctButton.Width(); // Store the original width
const auto sizNewButton = m_btnReset.SizeToContent(true); // This resizes the control!!!
if (sizNewButton.cx > nOrigWidth) // Compare to the original width rather than the new one
    m_btnReset.SizeToContent();
else // Restore original width
    m_btnReset.SetWindowPos(NULL, -1, -1, nOrigWidth, sizNewButton.cy, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

**Alternative Workaround:** 
Define a new `CMFCMenuButton`-based class, overriding `SizeToContent()` - in the implementation call the base `CMFCButton::SizeToContent()` with the `bCalcOnly` parameter passed by the caller, not with `FALSE`. Map the control to this class instead of `CMFCMenuButton`. That is use a class that fixes it. Too much of an overkill for just a workaround though.

Comment: Thank you, this works so I will stick with the caching of original width. Awesome. Although, I do have a few other menu buttons on some dialogs where I could make use of this again. Sounds like it is a bug in the MFC code and should be fixed by MS.